# How to not register multiple clicks in one click - Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So basically, I am writing a game where you have to click a button; when you do click it, your money goes up by 1. I am going to add more but for now, I am having a problem with my clicks.

What I mean by this is every time I click once multiple clicks are
registered. When I hold down my click it keeps clicking. I want to make it so that when I click it once only once click gets registered.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
x = 0
black = (0,0,0)
myfont2 = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",30)
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace",25)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (255,0,0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hackathon Theamatic Project!")
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,green,(250,250),75,0)
    text1 = myfont.render("Click Me",1,blue)
    screen.blit(text1,(190,230))
    text2 = myfont2.render("Money:"+str(x),1,blue)
    screen.blit(text2,(350,50))
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if event.button == 1:
            screen.fill(black)
            x = x+1
            print(x)
            if x == 5:
                x = 0
    pygame.display.update()
```

So yeah, if anyone of you could explain how to only register one click and show me the code that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the events in the event loop instead of the application loop (take care of the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)):

```py
# application loop
while True:

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

    # INDENTATION
    #-->|    
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                x = x+1
                print(x)
                if x == 5:
                    x = 0

    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,green,(250,250),75,0)
    text1 = myfont.render("Click Me",1,blue)
    screen.blit(text1,(190,230))
    text2 = myfont2.render("Money:"+str(x),1,blue)
    screen.blit(text2,(350,50))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I tried this but It doesn't change my multiple clicks being registered problem

Comment: @TheCodeMan You have to respect the indentation! Read my code carefully. I added a comment to the code in the answer.

Comment: thankyou Your answer worked I just copy and pasted it incorrectly